# Empty sequence when looping on a sequence for the second time

Tags: sequence, stanza

In stanza, I would like to loop two times over a sequence.

I have something like that:

```
public defn function1-and-function2 (s:Seqable<Double>) -> [Double, Double]:
   [function1(s), function2(s)]
```

with

```
public defn function1 (s:Seqable<Double>) -> Double
```

and

```
public defn function2 (s:Seqable<Shape>) -> Double
```

In both `function1` and `function2`, I am looping on the sequence. But when reaching `function2`, the sequence is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Seqable` is a lazily calculated sequence of values, and in general, you are only allowed to iterate through it once.

Thus, the general solution is to first store all of the values (e.g. in a tuple) and then you can pass this tuple to each of your functions:

```
val t = to-tuple(s)
[function1(t), function2(t)]
```

However, for your particular case, it is obvious that `function1` and `function2` can be calculated independently of each other. So it *is* possible to iterate through the sequence once, and then concurrently calculate the result of both `function1` and `function2`. There is a fancy function in `core` called `fork-on-seq` that lets you do this:

```
fork-on-seq(s, function1, function2)
```